# Where can I download for eclipse RSE ( Remote System Explorer ) offline plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to download the RSE Plugin ( Remote System Explorer) for eclipse for offline installation. Can someone help where can I find the plugin for offline installation.

I came across this page https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/remote-system-explorer-ssh-telnet-ftp-and-dstore-protocols , but can NOT figure out to download plugin. It only guides how to install the plugin.

Comment: Looks like your post was a little cut off?

Answer (score 0):

It's another Marketplace entry seemingly abandoned by that submitter. Clicking the Home icon for the entry takes you to the Target Management project's home page, which has a Downloads link on the right:

https://www.eclipse.org/tm/downloads.php